# MySQL Statement (Group and SUM() => getting multiple "sum" result per line

Tags: mysql, sum

I have several tables:

```
table user:
id  firstname   lastname
1   John      Doe
2   Jane      Skith
3   will      Smith
...

table member:
member_id    member_user_id member_status member_activated_by
10         1              yes           partner 1
11         1              yes           partner 2
12         1              yes           partner 3
13         2              yes           partner 2
14         3              no            ----
...

table points:
points_id    points_user_id points_value points_date
10         1              10           2012-02-15 
11         2              15           2012-02-15 
12         2              20           2012-02-15 
13         1              5            2012-02-15 
14         3              30           2012-02-15 
15         1              12           2012-02-15 
...

So results SHOULD be:
 id1 - John Doe:   27 Points
 id2 - Jane Skith: 35 Points
 id3 - will Smith: nothing (not activated)
```

Problem is, that id1 brings 81 Points (as he has been actiavted 3 times ...)

This is my current mysql string (shortened...)

```
SELECT points_user_id, SUM( points_value ) AS points_total, id, firstname, lastname
FROM user
JOIN member ON member.member_user_id = user.id
JOIN points ON points.points_user_id = user.id
WHERE 1
AND member_status = 'yes'
GROUP BY points_user_id
ORDER BY points_total DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

.. so far it "almost" works as desired.

BUT: A user may have sevaral partners that activated him "into the activation" table.

Now when this is called, I get a duplication of points_total (it will be counted as many times, as the uesr has been activated by partners ... ) This does not make to much sense in a rankling list...

How can I get only "one" points_total for each user_id

Hope you understand, what I want to achieve ... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you clarify your tables, please? You list `activation` as a table, but it's not in the query. Conversely, the `member` table is in the query, but you don't list it in your tables. Finally, can you explicitly indicate which field in the query belongs to which table.

Comment: sorry, to much copy/paste here .. now all information should be in the question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this should work, instead of join with activation make a subselect where you will get only one row per user_id then join with this subselect, I'm not sure if this is the MySql sintax but it should show you the way. The only remark is that the fields that you choose inside the inner query may not change for a same user_id

```
SELECT user_id, SUM( point_row ) AS points_total, user_data...,...
    FROM points
    JOIN user_data AS UD
    ON UD.user_id = points.user_id

JOIN ( SELECT field1,field2,field3, MAX(activation.user_id) as user_id 
  FROM activation WHERE activation_info = 'yes'
  GROUP BY field1,field2,field3 AS ACTIV )  AS ACTIV
  ON user_data.user_id = AS ACTIV.user_id

WHERE points.points_status = '1'
AND   ACTIV.activation_info = 'yes'
GROUP BY points.user_id
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Comment: Hi Victor,thanks! Your answer showed me the direction to go - all works fint now.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without the full SELECT statement being shown.  Most, likely you will need to remove all fields from the select that are not unique to the user_id. Having non-unique values there will give your results across multiple rows.  Also it appears you should be sorting by points_total, not total.

Comment: This is the Select statement, that is beeing used:
SELECT points_user_id, SUM( points_value ) AS points_total, id, firstname, lastname
FROM user
JOIN member ON member.member_user_id = user.id
JOIN points ON points.points_user_id = user.id
WHERE 1
AND member_status = 'yes'
GROUP BY points_user_id
ORDER BY points_total DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 100

Question has been updated with it...

Comment: So what tables do each of the fields come from? It is good practice to utilize table references or table aliases when using joins across tables (it makes you query much more understandable to outside parties who may need to read it). Also if points_user_id and id are equal (as it appears from your joins), why would you have it twice in the select?